# ORA-01722: invalid number while running a stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a query where I am executing it and getting below error as

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Here is the query.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (tfc.linkid) spanid,
            TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code) AS maint_zone_code,
            TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name) AS maint_zone_name,
            SUM (tfc.mho_handover_cert) AS ne_length,
            TRUNC (tfc.created_date) AS offered_date     
       FROM app_lco.tbl_fip_checklist tfc
      WHERE     LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.linkid)) > 8
            AND LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.linkid)) < 21
            AND tfc.status = 'APPROVED'
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR (tfc.linkid),
            TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code),
            TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name),
            TRUNC(tfc.created_date);
```

Table description is below

```
Name                 Null Type           
-------------------- ---- --------------     
MHO_HANDOVER_CERT         VARCHAR2(20)   
STRAIGHT_LINE_DIAG        VARCHAR2(5)    
OFFERID                   VARCHAR2(10)   
CREATED_DATE              DATE           
SUBMITTED_BY              VARCHAR2(50)   
LINKID                    VARCHAR2(50)   
SPANID                    VARCHAR2(50)   
STATUS                    VARCHAR2(15)   
FILE_NAME                 VARCHAR2(1000) 
SAP_ID                    VARCHAR2(30)   
STATE_NAME                VARCHAR2(50)   
MZ_NAME                   VARCHAR2(70)   
MZ_CODE                   VARCHAR2(30)
```

Comment: You are doing a `SUM` on `mho_handover_cert` which is a `varchar2`. Oracle will do an implicit string to number conversion on every value, and if any value is has a non-numeric character it will throw this exception.

Comment: @PaulW: so how to handle this ?

Comment: @PaulW: can we add something in query so that it only selects which has only Numeric character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store numeric values in strings; if you want to store numeric values then use a `NUMBER`.

Fix your data first and then your query will work.

---

If you can't fix your data (why? You should fix it!) then, from Oracle 12, you can use `TO_NUMBER(value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)`:

```sql
SELECT linkid  AS spanid,
       mz_code AS maint_zone_code,
       mz_name AS maint_zone_name,
       SUM(TO_NUMBER(mho_handover_cert DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR))
         AS ne_length,
       TRUNC(created_date) AS offered_date     
FROM   app_lco.tbl_fip_checklist
WHERE  LENGTH(TRIM(linkid)) > 8
AND    LENGTH(TRIM(linkid)) < 21
AND    status = 'APPROVED'
GROUP BY
       linkid,
       mz_code,
       mz_name,
       TRUNC(created_date);
```

*Note: you do not need to use `TO_CHAR` on columns that are already `VARCHAR2`.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE app_lco.tbl_fip_checklist (linkid, mz_code, mz_name, mho_handover_cert, created_date, status) AS
  SELECT 'AAAAAAAAA', 'B', 'C', 'abc', DATE '1970-01-01', 'APPROVED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAAAAAAAA', 'B', 'C', '1'  , DATE '1970-01-01', 'APPROVED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAAAAAAAA', 'B', 'C', '2'  , DATE '1970-01-01', 'APPROVED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAAAAAAAA', 'B', 'C', '3e1', DATE '1970-01-01', 'APPROVED' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SPANID | MAINT_ZONE_CODE | MAINT_ZONE_NAME | NE_LENGTH | OFFERED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAAAAAA | B | C | 33 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aprPITVX)

Comment: can I set `0` in place of `NULL` ?

Comment: @Nad You can, but you should ask yourself whether you should? If you use `NULL` then you know when there are no numeric values. If you use `0` then you cannot be sure whether the values actually totalled 0 or if they were non-numeric values.